# Query sObject type with dynamic name

Tags: apex, soql, dynamic-soql, string

Can I create a list variable dynamically in Saleforce? Like this:

```
String objectName = 'Noise_Dictionary__C';
List<ObjectName> lstObject = new  List<ObjectName>([select id from ObjectName limit 10]);
```

Answer (score 4):

I like use `String.format` and `String.join` to avoid string manipulation, best thing about this method is- its truly dynamic.

Also, if you use sObjectName.SObjectType it gives proper API name.

And Object.FieldName gives API name of field.

An example below:

```
String strObjectName = '' + Account.SObjectType;
List<String> lstFields = new List<String>{ '' + Account.Id,'' + Account.Name };

String soqlTemplate = 'SELECT {0} FROM {1} LIMIT 10';

String soql = String.format(soqlTemplate, new List<String>{
    String.join(lstFields, ', '),
    strObjectName
});

System.debug('soql: ' + soql);

List<sObject> lstresult = Database.query(soql);
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use dynamic query as:

```
String objectName = 'Noise_Dictionary__c';
List<sObject> lstSObject = Database.query('select id from '+String.escapeSingleQuotes(objectName)+' limit 10');
System.debug('<<<lstSObject>>>> '+lstSObject);
```

Use `String.escaapeSingleQuotes()` to make the user entered input to be safe from external injections.

Comment: Recommanded to escape quotes with String.escapeSingleQuotes before doing that...